# Dim the back light to low battery level

Tags: screen, samsung-galaxy-ace, backlight

Even when I set the backlight onto its dimmest, it is still very bright when using it in the dark. However, when you have low battery it appears even dimmer, so I know it is possible to get it to that level.

Is there anyway to set it to this reduced level?

If it makes any difference, I am using a Galaxy Ace (2.3.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently using [Screen Filter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&hl=en). It reduces the brightness of your phone below the level of what Android OS provides. Works for me and is a good battery saver. Hope this helps.

Comment: Good find thanks :) Working perfectly so far, I also like the fact that I can set it to 50%, then still use the 3-tier brightness settings the stock power control provides. It's a lot easier on the eyes already, and if I get a battery saving then that's a real plus.

Comment: Glad to know that it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Dimmer](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=brightness&fdid=giraffine.dimmer) available on F-droid (an installable catalogue of FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) applications for the Android platform).

> #### Dimmer
>
> Lower brightness
>
> Lower the brightness beyond the limit through a filter.
>
> License: [Apache2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#apache2)

Current version (3.3.1) [apk](https://f-droid.org/repo/giraffine.dimmer_37.apk).

[image]